# Sticky footer not working with absolute position

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, sticky-footer

I need to repair my sticky footer and for some reason it is now working. I'm not sure why. I'm following the example from here:
[Bootstrap Sticky Footer](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)

I have added to my footer position: absolute; and on the example page this is working and the footer is not staying on the same position I resize the browser. However, in my example the footer stays always on the bottom of the screen, and I know how the position is working, but why in my case the position does not act like the example one. I'm using Wordpress, and Sage theme with bootstrap 3. Here you can see the example:
[My example page.](http://biserka.onesto.bg/bg/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B8/)

P.S.

Here is the code for the body of the page:

```
<body  <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <!--[if IE]>
      <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <?php _e('You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.', 'sage'); ?>
      </div>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php
      do_action('get_header');
      get_template_part('templates/header');
    ?>

    <div class="wrap container" role="document">
      <div class="content row">
        <main class="main">
          <?php include Wrapper\template_path(); ?>
        </main><!-- /.main -->
        <?php if (Setup\display_sidebar()) : ?>
          <aside class="sidebar">
            <?php include Wrapper\sidebar_path(); ?>
          </aside><!-- /.sidebar -->
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div><!-- /.content -->
    </div><!-- /.wrap -->

    <?php
    do_action('get_footer');
    if (!is_front_page()){
      get_template_part('templates/footer');
    }
    wp_footer();
    ?>


  </body>
```

And here is the css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 100px;

}

.biserka-footer {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    color: white;

    width: 100%;
    height: 13rem;
    clear:both;

    font-size: 0.8em;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code to your post it will increase your chance of getting help.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use positio fixed (not absolute)

```
 .biserka-footer {
   background-color: #3b3b3b;
   bottom: 0;
   clear: both;
   color: white;
   font-size: 0.8em;
   height: 13rem;
   position: fixed;  /* fixed and not absolute */
   width: 100%;
}
```

but if you don't want the footer at the bottom you can use relative

```
 .biserka-footer {
   background-color: #3b3b3b;
   bottom: 0;
   clear: both;
   color: white;
   font-size: 0.8em;
   height: 13rem;
   position: relative;  /* relati */
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hm the fixed position leaves alway the footer at the bottom. And I want the content to push the footer, and if the content doesn't take the whole screen  to stay on the bottom.

Comment: If i use relative, the footer is not fixed at the bottom, do i need to use in that case some push div ?
Please check my screenshot here:
http://prnt.sc/ahspld

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say that this worked for me. It seems that the example Bootstrap 3 for the sticky footer suggests you use `absolute` rather than `fixed`. Using `fixed` makes everything work great.